# Looking for a unique handwriting font for photos

Tags: photo-editing

Can anyone suggest a unique(looking good, easy to read, and best for signature my photo) handwriting font to use for a signature on my photos?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unique? If you by unique mean one that no photographer ever used before I think none of us can do that. Then the solution would be designing one yourself or pay someone for doing that.

Comment: @Hugo: I already update my question... Its  not only for me but looking good, easy to read, and best for signature my photo. Please advice hugo. Thanks

Comment: Is it for commercial use or only personal use?

Comment: @Hugo : no, use only for me (personal use)

Comment: I could see how this could be edited to stay on topic potentially, but it is pretty rough as is. Asking for a specific font name isn't really what this website is for. Instead maybe you could ask how to add a signature to a photo or what tools will do it.

Comment: @dpollitt: hi dpollitt, thanks for your suggestion. I have get answer for my question by Hugo. Get me still can ask on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Do you have Photoshop or similar?  If you are only going to use this 'font' to create a signature I would instead recommend creating a image of your signature and saving this as a custom brush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I would not recommend adding a signature (or a logo for that matter) to a photo. There are numerous reasons for that:

- It distracts the viewer from the photo itself (and isn't it the photo that should have all of the attention?).
- It may work as a deterrent regarding theft, but it sure does not prevent it. If you are an aspiring photographer the theft is the least of your worries and can even be a sign of success if it happens.
- It does not make you look more professional and a photo sold with a watermark is a deeply devaluated shadow of the clean photo without it.

If you decide to watermark you photos try to stick to classic fonts and avoid crazy ones. Make sure it's readable from afar and use capital letters if needed and possible. I can't recommend a single font but I find classic sans serif fonts the most pleasing to watch if there has to be a watermark.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I agree but I want to insert any signature for my personal photo (not commercial). I search on google and find jellyka, what do you think? (http://www.dafont.com/jellyka-estrya-s-handwriting.font)

Comment: @lui As I said before stick to classic fonts and avoid crazy ones, that's my take if you really have too. It's all personal preference though.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Hugo but if you insist on adding a signature to your photo, why not make it your hand writing? Not your real signature, that would be insecure, but just hand write your name?

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of tools that will let you turn your handwriting into a font. I've used [Fontifier](http://www.fontifier.com/) with fair results, but there are plenty of solutions if you search a little.